# Set a Header to a DatePicker in vuetify.js

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

Hello i want setup a header over a v-date-picker component. How i can do this?

[My idea is set a header over the component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WJ6j.jpg)

Comment: What code have you tried so far? Please edit your question and add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try it like this:

```
      <div>
        <v-menu
          lazy
          :close-on-content-click="false"
          v-model="menu"
          transition="scale-transition"
          offset-y
          full-width
          :nudge-right="40"
          max-width="290px"
          min-width="290px"
        >
          <v-text-field
            slot="activator"
            label="Picker in menu"
            v-model="date"
            prepend-icon="event"
            readonly
          ></v-text-field>
          <v-date-picker v-model="date" no-title scrollable actions>
            <template scope="{ save, cancel }">
              <v-card-actions>
                <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                <v-btn flat color="primary" @click="cancel">Cancel</v-btn>
                <v-btn flat color="primary" @click="save">OK</v-btn>
              </v-card-actions>
            </template>
          </v-date-picker>
        </v-menu>
     </div>

<scirpt>

 name: "YourClassName",
        props: {},
        components: {},
        data() {
            return {
                date: null,
                menu: false,
                modal: false
            };
        },
</script>
```

Hope this helps =)

EDIT: Btw, I can highly recommend Vuetify, you can search for components that you need in your frontend.
Look here: [Vuetify Date-Picker](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/date-pickers)

Comment: I'm looking at the documentation but I can't find anything about what I want to do.
Let me explain again.
I want to put above the date picker (above the calendar) a header or a text that explains where I am for example "start".

Thank you.

Comment: So something like <v-card-title> Start </v-card-title>?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `selected-items-text` property to set header text. Look here: [Vuetify v-date-picker API](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-date-picker/#props)